# Customization of Form Background Size

Tags: forms, google-api, google-forms

Basically, I just want to increase a form background size. I've 5 choices in one question and 1 of them is cut by the format of Google Forms. **How can I remove the bottom scroll bar and make it a static form ?**

[image: Bottom Scroll Bar]

---

[image: My Google Form]

Comment: I don't think that you can have any control over the scroll bar in a Google Form.

Comment: can't I have access to html of google form page ?

Comment: No, there is no built-in way to access the HTML or CSS in a Google Form.  There may be other ways to access the HTML in a browser, but your users would need to have something in their browser to accomplish that.  For example, a Google Chrome extension can have some access to the HTML.  But even if something like a Chrome extension could change the HTML, all your users would need to be using Chrome, and have the extension installed.  Google Forms are for basic input needs.  A Google Form has no features for anything other than basic input use.

Comment: Thank you for helping me! Thats is all I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time the new Google Forms themes feature only allows to select predefined themes and to change the theme image. The old Google Forms themes feature have more customization options but it doesn't include one for changing the grid question box size.

If you are using the old Google Forms try changing the font settings for the question options.

Another alternative is to split the column headers words (replace `moderadamente` by `modera- mente` or by a shorter synonym)

A third alternative is to use a code like 1,2,3,4,5 instead of category names.